# Can I import or include pre_tasks or post_tasks on a playbook?

Tags: ansible

there are several playbooks and I want to add same pre_tasks and post_tasks to those playbooks. so I add the import_tasks to playbooks. look like this

```
---
- hosts: central
  tasks:
  - import_tasks: pre_tasks.yml
  roles:
  - do_something
  become: no
```

but I got this error

> ERROR! included task files must contain a list of tasks

How I import pre_tasks to the playbook or is there a better way to apply pre_tasks/post_tasks to multiple playbooks?

Comment: You would be better served putting those tasks in another role.

Comment: What is your problem? Don't you understand the error? File *pre_tasks.yml* "must contain a list of tasks". Better ways? For what use-case? There is [Including and Importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#including-and-importing) of tasks, playbooks, roles.

Answer (score 4):

You can import pre_tasks or post_tasks in a playbook.

Here's an example where we have playbook.yml and common.yml - If we want to include common.yml into playbook.yml, then this example shows how to correctly structure the files:

**playbook.yml**

```
- hosts: haproxy  
  pre_tasks: 
  - name: Import common tasks
    import_tasks: 'common.yml'

  tasks:  
  - debug:
      msg: 'Hello from playbook.yml'
```

**common.yml** (This is wrong and will reproduce your error if called from a script like the one int the question)

```
pre_tasks:
  - debug: 
      msg: 'Hello from common.yml'
```

**common.yml** (correct import structure)

```
- debug: 
    msg: 'Hello from common.yml'
```

So the key is not to include the `pre_tasks` or `post_tasks`  directive in your included file. Doing so will create the same error that you mentioned